# How can i change the font on ttk.Entry

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts, tkinter-entry

Is there any way to change the ttk.Entry font I've tried with the ttk.style but TypeError occurs.

Like:

```
my_style = ttk.Style('TEntry' , font = ('Arial' , 10 , 'bold'))
my_entry = ttk.Entry(master)
my_entry.pack()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Specify font in `ttk.Entry` constructor.

For example:

```
from Tkinter import * # from tkinter import *    IN Python 3.x
import ttk

master = Tk()
my_entry = ttk.Entry(master, font=('Arial', 10, 'bold')) # <-----
my_entry.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: YES SIR!!!
I fill so idiot that i didnt try that before i ask but i thought that all ttk widgets use the style class to specify the font options , 
THANK you very much!

Comment: Apropos @LuciusSilanus’s comment, the problem is apparently with the underlying `ttk` library, and not with Python itself. It’s unclear _why_ you can’t style `ttk.Entry`.